# Bookmarkable URL in JSF application - Trying to use Spring Webflow and JSF . Any suggestions?

Tags: jsf, friendly-url, spring-webflow

Our application is JSF , hibernate & Spring. Currently the url is in following format 
http://www.skill-guru.com/skill/login/testDetails.faces?testId=62&testName=PMP-Certification-practice-test

We want a clean url  like http://www.skill-guru.com/urltitle?some parameter

One of the ways we could do this is through integration with Spring webflow with JSF.

Any other suggestions ?

We are trying Spring webflow 1.0 with JSF 2.0 but that does not seem to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[PrettyFaces](http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces/) provides beautiful URLs for JSF applications.

You can always use the [UrlRewriteFilter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/)

Comment: That seems to be a very good solution. Thanks Bozho. I love stackoverflow.

Comment: An update to what we were doing. We are using pretty faces to get Bookmark-able URl's and they are awesome. Thanks to Lincoln for creating the utility. JSF 2.0 would not have solved our problem completely.
In case you are interested , have a look at he URL's in Skill-Guru (http://www.skill-guru.com)

Comment: If you are not using JSF, UrlRewriteFilter is the way to go